# Is there any way of capitalize the first letter of the month in date hierarchy?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need a way to capitalize the first letter of the month in date hierarchy to use them in a matrix.

I tried to do the following column:

```
month = SWITCH(TRUE(),
    MONTH('table'[date]) = 1, "January",
    MONTH('table'[date]) = 2, "February",
    MONTH('table'[date]) = 3, "March",
    MONTH('table'[date]) = 4, "April",
    MONTH('table'[date]) = 5, "May",
    MONTH('table'[date]) = 6, "June",
    MONTH('table'[date]) = 7, "July",
    MONTH('table'[date]) = 8, "August",
    MONTH('table'[date]) = 9, "September",
    MONTH('table'[date]) = 10, "October",
    MONTH('table'[date]) = 11, "November",
    MONTH('table'[date]) = 12, "December")
```

It worked, but when I use that in the matrix, the months are sorted by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alphabetical sort is the default for all columns. You need to add a sorting column and specify this for your original column.